# Is there a reason why I would not receive a conversationUpdate (membersAdded) event when my bot was installed to a new team?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, office365, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a user that is running into an issue when installing my Microsoft Teams bot to their teams. Here is what they are seeing:

1. User installed bot to 1st team. We received the conversationUpdate event and we sent a welcome message to the General channel for that team.
2. User attempts to install bot into a 2nd team. It appears that we never received the conversationUpdate event. And since we don't receive the conversationUpdate event, we never sent a welcome message to this 2nd team. The user has tried uninstalling and reinstalling the bot, but subsequent installation attempts don't seem to trigger the conversationUpdate event either.

The user sent screenshots of their installed apps list for team 1 and 2, and it lists my bot as installed for both teams. We can also send messages to both teams 1 and 2.

Why would team 2 not send us a conversationUpdate event? Not only do we rely on this conversationUpdate event to send a welcome message, we save the serviceUrl, tenantId, and teamId included in the conversationUpdate event payload. So if we don't get this conversationUpdate event payload, this causes issues when trying to send messages later.

Does anyone have any idea why we only saw the conversationUpdate event for the first team they installed our app to? Are there any MS Teams settings that could impact this? I know there was an outage at the beginning of April 2021 and another outage today April 27th 2021, but we saw these issues last week on April 22nd/23rd, so I would assume this is unrelated to the outages.

A few more notes:

- None of our other users have reported this issue.
- I would see an error in my logs if I received a conversationUpdate event without a tenantId/serviceUrl/teamId/generalChannelId. I would also see an error in my logs if I attempted to send a welcome message and received a non-200 response. This leads me to believe we aren't receiving the conversationUpdate event altogether, since I haven't seen any errors parsing conversationUpdate events or sending welcome messages.

Let me know if there is any more info I could provide that would help.

Comment: (1) When an anonymous user is added to a meeting, membersAdded payload object does not have aadObjectId field - this is by design. I am not sure you're having this scenario?

Comment: (2) You need to understand that the conversationUpdate event with the membersRemoved object in the payload is sent when either your bot is removed from a team, or a user is removed from a team where a bot has been added. Microsoft Teams also adds eventType.teamMemberRemoved in the channelData object. As with the membersAdded object, you should parse the membersRemoved object for your bot's App ID to determine who was removed.

Comment: @Mason Stricklin - Please let us know does that help clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the Answer for better knowledge

Copying from @Dev comments

(1) When an anonymous user is added to a meeting, membersAdded payload object does not have aadObjectId field - this is by design. I am not sure you're having this scenario?

(2) You need to understand that the conversationUpdate event with the membersRemoved object in the payload is sent when either your bot is removed from a team, or a user is removed from a team where a bot has been added. Microsoft Teams also adds eventType.teamMemberRemoved in the channelData object. As with the membersAdded object, you should parse the membersRemoved object for your bot's App ID to determine who was removed.